# image is stuck on top left of the screen

Tags: html

https://jsfiddle.net/fc90p0bf/

```
<body>
        <div id = "main" class = "header">
            <div id = "logo">
            <a href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html">
            <img src = "reddit_web.png"/> </a>
            </div>
      </div>

}
#main.header{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #232f3e;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1800px;
    min-width: 1217px;
}
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 46px;
}
```

the image is stuck to the top left but i have the positioning in relative. how do i fix this?

Comment: I recommend reading this... http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div is positioned absolutely so the img is ignoring it and positioning itself as the first item which would be in the top left.
I assume you want it below the div, so you either need to edit the positioning of the img or you need to change div to `position: relative` as well.